# Problemas en la actualización del composer.json en Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel-5, composer

Buenas tardes vengo desarrollando un proyecto con Laravel 5.6, y al actualizar el composer.json, debido que necesitaba instalar una nueva dependencia, al momento de finalizar la actualización me salio el siguiente error:

```
Package phpoffice/phpexcel is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use 
phpoffice/phpspreadsheet instead.
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, 
"JakubOnderka\PhpConsoleColor\ConsoleColor" was found in both 
"C:/xampp/htdocs/Recaudaciones/vendor/jakub-onderka/php-console- 
color/src\ConsoleColor.php" and "C:/xampp/htdocs/Recaudaciones/vendor/jakub- 
onderka/php-console-color/src\JakubOnderka\PhpConsoleColor\ConsoleColor.php", 
the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, 
"JakubOnderka\PhpConsoleColor\InvalidStyleException" was found in both 
"C:/xampp/htdocs/Recaudaciones/vendor/jakub-onderka/php-console- 
color/src\InvalidStyleException.php" and 
"C:/xampp/htdocs/Recaudaciones/vendor/jakub-onderka/php-console- 
color/src\JakubOnderka\PhpConsoleColor\InvalidStyleException.php", the first 
will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, 
"PharIo\Version\AbstractVersionConstraint" was found in both 
"C:\xampp\htdocs\Recaudaciones\vendor/phar- 
io/version/src\AbstractVersionConstraint.php" and 
"C:\xampp\htdocs\Recaudaciones\vendor/phar- 
io/version/src\constraints\AbstractVersionConstraint.php", the first will be 
used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, 
"PharIo\Version\AndVersionConstraintGroup" was found in both 
"C:\xampp\htdocs\Recaudaciones\vendor/phar- 
io/version/src\AndVersionConstraintGroup.php" and 
"C:\xampp\htdocs\Recaudaciones\vendor/phar- 
io/version/src\constraints\AndVersionConstraintGroup.php", the first will be 
used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "PharIo\Version\AnyVersionConstraint" 
was 
found in both "C:\xampp\htdocs\Recaudaciones\vendor/phar- 
io/version/src\AnyVersionConstraint.php" and 
"C:\xampp\htdocs\Recaudaciones\vendor/phar- 
io/version/src\constraints\AnyVersionConstraint.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "PharIo\Version\ExactVersionConstraint" 
was found in both "C:\xampp\htdocs\Recaudaciones\vendor/phar- 
io/version/src\constraints\ExactVersionConstraint.php" and 
"C:\xampp\htdocs\Recaudaciones\vendor/phar- 
io/version/src\ExactVersionConstraint.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "PharIo\Version\Exception" was found in 
both "C:\xampp\htdocs\Recaudaciones\vendor/phar-io/version/src\Exception.php" 
and "C:\xampp\htdocs\Recaudaciones\vendor/phar- 
io/version/src\exceptions\Exception.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, 
"PharIo\Version\GreaterThanOrEqualToVersionConstraint" was found in both 
"C:\xampp\htdocs\Recaudaciones\vendor/phar- 
io/version/src\constraints\GreaterThanOrEqualToVersionConstraint.php" and 
"C:\xampp\htdocs\Recaudaciones\vendor/phar- 
io/version/src\GreaterThanOrEqualToVersionConstraint.php", the first will be 
used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "PharIo\Version\InvalidVersionException" 
was found in both "C:\xampp\htdocs\Recaudaciones\vendor/phar- 
io/version/src\exceptions\InvalidVersionException.php" and 
"C:\xampp\htdocs\Recaudaciones\vendor/phar- 
io/version/src\InvalidVersionException.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, 
"PharIo\Version\OrVersionConstraintGroup" 
was found in both "C:\xampp\htdocs\Recaudaciones\vendor/phar- 
io/version/src\constraints\OrVersionConstraintGroup.php" and 
"C:\xampp\htdocs\Recaudaciones\vendor/phar- 
io/version/src\OrVersionConstraintGroup.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, 
"PharIo\Version\SpecificMajorAndMinorVersionConstraint" was found in both 
"C:\xampp\htdocs\Recaudaciones\vendor/phar- 
io/version/src\constraints\SpecificMajorAndMinorVersionConstraint.php" and 
"C:\xampp\htdocs\Recaudaciones\vendor/phar- 
io/version/src\SpecificMajorAndMinorVersionConstraint.php", the first will be 
used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, 
"PharIo\Version\SpecificMajorVersionConstraint" was found in both 
"C:\xampp\htdocs\Recaudaciones\vendor/phar- 
io/version/src\constraints\SpecificMajorVersionConstraint.php" and 
"C:\xampp\htdocs\Recaudaciones\vendor/phar- 
io/version/src\SpecificMajorVersionConstraint.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, 
"PharIo\Version\UnsupportedVersionConstraintException" was found in both 
"C:\xampp\htdocs\Recaudaciones\vendor/phar- 
io/version/src\exceptions\UnsupportedVersionConstraintException.php" and 
"C:\xampp\htdocs\Recaudaciones\vendor/phar- 
io/version/src\UnsupportedVersionConstraintException.php", the first will be 
used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "PharIo\Version\VersionConstraint" was 
found in both "C:\xampp\htdocs\Recaudaciones\vendor/phar- 
io/version/src\constraints\VersionConstraint.php" and 
"C:\xampp\htdocs\Recaudaciones\vendor/phar- 
io/version/src\VersionConstraint.php", the first will be used.
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover
Discovered Package: barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: intervention/image
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: maatwebsite/excel
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
```

Que significan estos errores y cual seria la solución?

Comment: Te indica al inicio que el package que estás usando está abandonado y te indica cuál deberías usar

Comment: Gracias por responder, el problema es que la aplicación  trabajaba con el paquete maatwebsite/excel para hacer importación de datos desde un archivo excell y phpoffice/phpspreadsheet según lo que había averiguado no contempla la importación.

Comment: Pero el problema mayor es por las clases ambiguas, aquí hay abierto un issue que no ha sido resuelto https://github.com/phar-io/version/issues/14

Comment: Muchas gracias estaré atento a las respuestas de ese post porque ese es otro gran problema